# How to obtain closed form of this recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I have to solve a the following recurrence through iteration. I also show the steps. The issues is I have no idea how to get to the closed form! I can tell there's a pattern, but I don't know how to "condense" it into the closed form.

\begin{align*}
T(n) = nT(n - 1) + 1\\
T(n) &= n((n - 1)T(n - 2) + 1) + 1\\
T(n) &= n(n - 1)T(n - 2) + n + 1 \\
T(n) &= n(n-1)(n-2)T(n-3) + n(n-1) + n + 1 \\
T(n) &= n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)T(n-4) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1) + n + 1
\end{align*}

Some direction or explanation would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks :)

Comment: you will require the value of $T(1)$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480899/how-to-solve-recurrence-tn-ntn-1-1?rq=1

Comment: @happymath all that's given is T(n) = $\theta$(1) for n $\leq$ 1.

Comment: Take the initial terms $1, 3, 10, 41, 206, 1237, 8660, 69281, 623530, 6235301, \ldots$ and then try [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+3%2C+10%2C+41%2C+206%2C+1237%2C+8660%2C+69281%2C+623530%2C+6235301&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: @Henry what are you even talking about?? And what happened to one of the answers someone posted!!!!

Comment: As @Henry pointed out, this is [OEIS A002627](https://oeis.org/A002627) in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences; the entry there has only a couple of elementary closed forms, neither particularly nice: $$n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k!}$$ and $$\lfloor n!(e-1)\rfloor\;.$$ You won’t do any better than this.

Comment: I'm starting to think I'm way overthinking this question. This is an introductory undergraduate level discrete math class. We haven't talked about gamma functions or anything.

Comment: @Brian: I think those are nice

Comment: @Henry: I meant nice from the elementary undergraduate standpoint. In that context the first wouldn’t usually even be considered a closed form, and I’d not expect students to be able to derive the second from the first.

Answer (score 1):

In [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480899/how-to-solve-recurrence-tn-ntn-1-1ur), your received nice answers.

Continuing in the same spirit and trying to find a closed form, the given results can "simplify" to $$T(n)=(c-1)\, n!+e \,\Gamma (n+1,1)$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function $(c=T(0))$.